# Почему не работает startActivity(intent) android?

Tags: android

Я реализовал в приложении возможность сохранить пользователя при первой попытке логина, чтобы потом не нужно было постоянно вводить пароль и логин. Теперь, если пользователь впервые пользуется приложением, вводит логин и пароль, программа сохраняет `refresh_token`, и дальше при следующем запуске приложения идет проверка на наличие сохраненной переменной. Если переменная есть, то мы переходим на следующий экран.

Вроде бы все работает, но почему-то начали вылезать разнообразные проблемы, одной из них есть отсутствие возможности выйти на первое активити. У меня в `actionbar` есть кнопка для перехода на первое активити, но теперь, после того как я сделал запоминание пользователя, она не работает так как нужно. Теперь при нажатии на эту кнопку, я никуда не перехожу, то есть, опять открывается второе активити, а если все-таки мне удается попасть на первое активити, путем нажатия кнопки назад, то кнопка логина не работает и по-факту первое активити не работает.

Comment: Вы задали такое условие, что если юзер однажды залогинился, то первая активность при старте перебрасывает на вторую. Если Вы хотите сделать выход из аккаунта, то перед возвращением в первую активность удалите или измените запись о том, что юзер залогинен, что бы, условие на старт второй активности не было пройдено

Comment: Очень размытое объяснение ошибки, нужно хотя бы выложить код ошибки...

Comment: ошибки как-бы и нету, то есть студия нормально реагирует на все, логов нету, а вот перейти на первое активити не могу, может как-то по-другому нужно стартовать другое активити? в стеке просто активити нету, может нужно как-то еще ее инициализировать?

Comment: Теперь окончательно запутался, вы можете выложить исходный код?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка была в том что я не менял значение bool переменной которая отвечала за то пользовался ли приложением человек, если во время первого логина человек присваивает этой переменной true, что означало что на этом устройстве не нужно повторно предлагать входить в акк. Я же при попытке выйти из акк, удалял только идентификаторы из файлов настроек, а переменную hasVisited оставлял true, и дальше когда я пытался перейти на первое активити мне автоматически перебрасывало на второе активити так как переменная была true, проверка этой переменной у меня стоит в функции onCreate что означало, что при старте активити у меня сначала проверялась переменная hasVisited. Спасибо @woesss за то что натолкнул на правильное решение. Теперь у меня все работает как нужно. Не уверен что мой ответ кому-нибудь сильно поможет, но я надеюсь что мою ошибку никто не допустит.